# Where is G-d according to Judaism?

Tags: theology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hashem is here and there and everywhere?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/876/hashem-is-here-and-there-and-everywhere)

Sometimes to make the idea controversial, atheists depict G-d as a humanly being residing in the space. Then compare this to other fairy tale creatures. To counter this, some sort of logical or may be philosophical answer is needed to the question, "**Where** is G-d?"
What is the position of Judaism about this subject?

Comment: I think the appropriate answer to "Where is God?" is "No."

Comment: related? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2424/hashem-is-here-hashem-is-there-really

Comment: @Dan Wow! Good call.

Comment: Also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/876/hashem-is-here-and-there-and-everywhere

Comment: @DoubleAA But still interested in your answer "No". How is that?

Comment: @DoubleAA I'd prefer "yes"...

Comment: @Gulshan The concept of "where" or place doesn't exist when referring to God. God created the concept of "place", so in some ways every place is inside of God, and God is not inside himself - the very concept of place doesn't exist when referring to God. Place is a concept of physicality, but physicality only exists because God created it. It would be like a character in a book actually writing the book.